# How to bind dropdown value to a url and then use this url to fetch data in a textfield?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a dropdown with some values. When a user selects some values i want these values to be bound to a url as a parameter value and then use this url to fetch data in a textfield.

I just dont know how to perform fetch here and then populate the textfield.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance!
Ronan

Comment: Please paste some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of step need to follow to perform this task, like

1. you have to create the url based on the Select value, Like

   var url="http://yourdomain?value="+SELECTVALUE;
2. Then perform a AJAX request with this url ($.ajax) in jquery
3. Set the response in the textfield.

You will get the ajax call process and response type text in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks Sudip! The approach you have suggested makes sense to me. I am new to javascript and need to know how these steps can be performed. For e.g if i have adropdown like: <select id="foo" name="foo" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</select> and i select an option here then:1. after binding parameter to url how can i make an ajax call if my url is http://www.testing.aspx/api/taskrequests/serialId={selectedValue} and then fetch the response which is in json format to a textfield. Thanks!

Comment: I hope you are calling an onchange function when user change the value or select the value from drop-down. Store the {selectedValue} in a variable and pass it into the ajax function, like $.ajax({  type: "GET",  url: "YOURURL",data: {serialIs : STORED-VAL},  dataType: "JSON",success: function(data){SET THE DATA INTO YOUR TXTFIELD}}); Now how to set: $('#TEXTFIELDID').html(data); (should be inside the ajax success function). Hope it works..

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$('form').serialize();` jQuery method and then pass it as `jQuery.ajax()` data.

**Example**

```
<select id="foo" name="foo" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

in js var `str = $("form").serialize();`

will result in a query string that looks like

```
[path]?foo=1&foo=2&foo=3&someotherparams...
```

**more clear example**

```
$("#FormSubmit").click(function()
{
    var str = $("#ShowForm").serialize();
    $.post("url.php", str , function(data) {...}); 
});
```